# Get length of line in Java file using python

Tags: python

I want to be able to get the length of each line of a java file using python ignoring spaces and white space. I would eventually put each line length into an array. Take this java file:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello world");
    } 

}
```

The array for this file would read:

```
{22,34,33,1,1,}
```

what is the best way to go about this? I am more than capable of creating the array but how can I go about finding the length of each line?

Comment: Can you split the file up in an array of lines, iterating through them, getting their lengths by lines[i].count()?

Comment: You can use build in len() after you replace white space with nothing.

Comment: how do you get 34 for the second line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing  on the part of your question "how can I go about finding the length of each line?", you can use this code.

```
bad_chars = ' \t\n\r'

def count_chars():
    with open('someclass.java', 'r') as javafile:
        for line in javafile:
            cleaned = filter(lambda c: c not in bad_chars, line)
            if cleaned:
                yield len(cleaned)
```

You definitely can and should refactor this to meet your needs (perhaps having the java filename as a function argument), but this should give you non-whitespace counts, as defined by not including characters in `bad_chars`.

RETURNS:

```
>>> print list(count_chars())
[22, 35, 33, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `{a, b, c}` notation in Python is a `set`, which you don't want (no duplicate items allowed); try a `list`, `[a, b, c]`.

To remove whitespace from the start and end of the lines, use `str.strip()`; this will remove tabs/spaces/newlines at the start and end of the line. To remove spaces from inside the line, use `str.replace(' ', '')`. Once you have stripped the extra characters, the length of the line is simply `len(line)`.

You can use a list comprehension to create the list in one step, for file `f`:

```
output = [len(l) for l in (line.strip().replace(' ', '') 
                           for line in f) if len(l) > 0]
```

gives me `[22, 35, 33, 1, 1]`.

Comment: OP wanted to get rid of white spaces, not only ' '.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
    for line in open('file.java', 'r'):
        lineLength = len(line.replace(' ', ''))
```

Comment: His expected output matches the number of non-whitespace characters in each line, not just on the ends. Plus, he said "ignoring spaces and white space".

Comment: ahh thanks ... I still dont get 34 for the second line ... but yeah reading comprehension :P

Comment: Yeah, not sure if I miscounted or he did, but I counted 35 non-whitespace, and there would be closer to 40 with whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
with open('input') as f:
    output = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        if line != [] :
            line = "".join(line)
            output.append(len(line))
    print output
```